# where to find a real example on flex and bison?

Tags: bison, lex

i need a n example on flex and bison , so i can learn how to build ast tree and symbol table and do semantic  analysis

Comment: I just thought I'd add (a bit late) that Bison itself is written in Bison, and probably very good Bison: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bison.git

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PostgreSQL: http://anoncvs.postgresql.org/cvsweb.cgi/pgsql/src/backend/parser/

Answer (score 6):

This link: [Using Flex and Bison](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.16/16.07/UsingFlexandBison/) is really good. It describes how they work and afterwards explains step-by-step how to build a small programming language.